# Inheritance in BEM

Tags: css, inheritance, sass, dry, bem

I have a couple of cases of misused BEM on hand where a hierarchy of blocks has been botched from start, this results in WET CSS code that is hard to maintain.

To put it simply:

```
.about-us {
  &__title {
    font-size: ...; // Same
    font-weight: ...; // Same
  }
  &__content {
    font-size: ...; // Same
  }

  &__faces { ... } // Different;
}

.catalogue {
  &__title {
    font-size: ...; // Same
    font-weight: ...;  // Same
  }
  &__content {
    font-size: ...;  // Same

    &-features { ... } // Different
  }
  ...
}

.catalogue-item {
  &__title {
    font-size: ...; // Same
    font-weight: ...;  // Same
    text-align: ...; // Different
  }
  &__content {
    font-size: ...;  // Same
  }
  ...
}
```

It was assumed that the style of different pages may vary, but almost all styles that are responsible for general website appearance (typography, etc) efficiently stay the same - or at least, they should.

Are specific styles supposed to inherit from common ones? E.g

```
.catalogue {
  &__title {
    @extends .page__title;
    ...
```

Should they just coexist? E.g.

```
<div class="page catalogue">
  <h1 class="page__title catalogue__title">...
```

Real examples are much more complicated, so a specific fix for the code won't work. What I'd like to know is how BEM methodology addresses such cases in general and what are common approaches for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in my book. That would violate the purpose of BEM in the first place.

You see, the main reason why you should stick to something like BEM is: separation of concerns. You might call it encapsulation.

If you start using general CSS classes you'll break up the encapsulation and CSS rules will be all over the place. That's not what you want. It will be harder to maintain as it will make the testing very, very, **very** aufwendig and error prone.

Since you are using SASS, you might want to go for something like this.

```
$global-font-size-normal: X;
$global-font-weight-normal: Y;
$global-font-size-extra: A;
$global-font-weight-extra: B;

// ...

$about_us-font-size: $global-font-size-normal;
$about_us-font-weight: $global-font-weight-normal;
$about_us_faces-font-size: $global-font-size-extra;

.about-us {
  &__title {
    font-size: $about_us-font-size;
    font-weight: $about_us-font-weight;
  }
  &__content {
    font-size: $about_us-font-size;
  }

  &__faces { 
    font-size: $about_us_faces-font-size;
  };
}

// ... etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

BEM only describes what your class names should be; you can arrange your CSS however you like. Using style inheritance to add common styles to specific classes works well, as you've discovered.

```html
<div class="page catalogue">
  <h1 class="page__title catalogue__title">...
```

In this example, your `<h1>` should just have the `catalogue__title` class. If you want a `catalogue__title` to look like a `page__title`, you describe that in your CSS - using inheritence, for example.